# A npm library is not working when using docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, webpack

I try to Dockerize a React app that uses webpack. Everything is working properly when I run my app locally (on MacOS).

But when I use docker I get a the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/containers/fenetre_log.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ROSLIB' in '/usr/src/app/src/containers'
```

The strange thing is that roslib is well declared as a dependency in my package.json...

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "eslint": "^4.6.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.3.0",
    "gh-pages": "^1.1.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^4.26.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "react": "16.2",
    "react-dom": "16.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-promise": "^0.6.0",
    "roslib": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --host 0.0.0.0",
    "lint": "eslint './src/**/*.js' './src/**/*.jsx'",
    "deploy": "webpack -p && gh-pages -d dist"
  }
}
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Docker Image which is used as foundation to create
# a custom Docker Image with this Dockerfile
FROM node:10
 
# A directory within the virtualized Docker environment
# Becomes more relevant when using Docker Compose later
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 
# Copies package.json and package-lock.json to Docker environment
COPY package*.json ./
 
# Installs all node packages
RUN npm install
 
# Copies everything over to Docker environment (except the .dockerignore files {cf bellow})
COPY . .
 
# Uses port which is used by the actual application
EXPOSE 8080
 
# Finally runs the application
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

From where do you think the error message can come from ?

Here are the command I used to build and run the container:

```
docker build -t front-end .

docker run -tid --name front-end front-end
```

Then I checked the logs with :

```
docker logs front-end
```

Here is the .dockerignore :

```
/node_modules
```

Comment: Would you mind adding the output of the build command?

Comment: `COPY . .` are you copying over your `node_modules` from working directory? Is there a `.dockerignore`?

Comment: When you run your image, are you using Compose `volumes:` or a `docker run -v` option to tell Docker to use an old version of your `node_modules` directory, instead of what's in the image?

Comment: @MarkoE done at the end of the description.

Comment: @Aivaras Yes there is, with only /node_modules in it

Comment: @DavidMaze I didn't use the -v option, I added the command I ran in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the actual code where the error originates, it's difficult to pinpoint the problem. If for some reason you cannot share your code publicly you can try below:

1. Debug the problem inside the docker image using docker which gives you shell access.

```
docker run -it [IMAGE_ID] sh
```

2. Check your imports if proper casing is followed. Apparently some have encountered a similar problem where the modules import in OSX is case insensitive but not in linux.

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1741

3. Maybe the package you are looking for is installed in your global npm modules and was not included in package.json. This results to the module not installed in the docker image.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The solution of my problem was in the second point of your answer: 
" the modules import in OSX is case insensitive but not in linux"
Thank you so much